# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'public' (T_PUBLIC) in codeifniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm creating `core/MY_Controller.php` file form a codeigniter tutorial movie , and my code is :

```
<?php
/**
* MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
*/
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        public $username;
        $slogin = $this->input->cookie('userblog');
        if (!empty($slogin)) 
        {
            $this->load->library('encrypt');
            $login = $this->encrypt->decode($slogin,ENCRYPT_KEY) ;
            echo 'login is : ' .$login ;
            $login_info = explode('_',$login) ;
            $this->username = $login_info[0] ;
            $is_login = $login_info[1];
            if ( $is_login !='islogin')
            {
                redirrect('login');
            }
        }
        $login = $this->session->userdata('login') ;
        if(!empty($login))
        {
            if ($login != true) 
            {
                redirect('login');
            }
        }
        else
        {
            redirect('login');
        }
    }
}

?>
```

this is the **exact code** that the teacher has written , but when I want run it page tells me this error `public $username;` :

```
 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'public' (T_PUBLIC) in D:\Software\wamp\www\ci\admin\application\core\MY_Controller.php on line 11
```

I checked my code several times and I have Compared it with the teachers code but I have no foud any difference between them  , but jusy his code works well

Comment: You define class properties __outside__ of class methods: `public $username;` should be defined before your constructor, not inside it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this error occurs because you declare $username within a method. You shouldn't. 
Use this instead, it declares it outside of the method, and inside of the class.

```
<?php
/**
* MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
*/
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{

    public $username;

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $slogin = $this->input->cookie('userblog');
        if (!empty($slogin)) 
        {
            $this->load->library('encrypt');
            $login = $this->encrypt->decode($slogin,ENCRYPT_KEY) ;
            echo 'login is : ' .$login ;
            $login_info = explode('_',$login) ;
            $this->username = $login_info[0] ;
            $is_login = $login_info[1];
            if ( $is_login !='islogin')
            {
                redirrect('login');
            }
        }
        $login = $this->session->userdata('login') ;
        if(!empty($login))
        {
            if ($login != true) 
            {
                redirect('login');
            }
        }
        else
        {
            redirect('login');
        }
    }
}

?>
```